# Generate a randomly shuffled list with uniform element frequency

Tags: python, list, random, frequency, shuffle

I want to code a test unit in Django/Python and I need to create a table with one column filled with integers chosen from `(1,2,3,4)` such that the frequency of each integer is the same, but the column has random order.

I am trying to generate a random list in order to create this table. The list should contain 64 elements, and should have:

- 16 elements as `1`
- 16 elements as `2`
- 16 elements as `3`
- 16 elements as `4`

I have tried using [`random.randint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) but the resulting list did not have equally distributed elements.

I have read about [`random.uniform`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.uniform) but it just seems to return a float.

```
from random import uniform
for i in (range(1,65)):
    r = uniform(1,4)
```

Output:

```
>>> r
1.184941440487669
```

Answer (score 9):

You could do the following:

```
import random
a = [1,2,3,4]*16
random.shuffle(a)
```

[random.shuffle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) randomly shuffles the list `a` in place. The value of `a` will then be a list with the given element frequencies, randomly ordered.

Answer (score 3):

If you want exactly 16 occurrences of each number, `random.shuffle()` is the way to go. But if you just want a random array were each element has the same probability, you could use `random.randrange()`. This function accepts the same arguments as `range()`.

Note that the numbers won't occur with exactly the same frequency, only randomly approximated:

```py
import random

a = [random.randrange(1,5) for _ in range(64)]
print(a)
for i in range(1,5):
    print(i, 'occurs', a.count(i), 'times')
```

Output of a test run:

```
[3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 1, 4, 1, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 1, 3, 4, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3]
1 occurs 15 times
2 occurs 21 times
3 occurs 14 times
4 occurs 14 times
```